# How to iterate over all Opptys and their line items- in bulk with map?

Tags: apex, map

While in a trigger, 
I want to iterate over all Opportunities (opptys) and their related OpportunityLineItems (olis).
This is the pseudo code I use, and problem I face is how do I iterate over all the olis, while already looping in the oppty FOR loop

```
 //prepare the list of oppties ids
   Id[] oppids = new Id[]{};
   for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
   oppids.add(opp.Id);
   }
```

Now to create a map of all the opptys and their olis:
I am not sure this is correct map, or should it be opportunitylineitem object.

```
 map<id, Opportunity> opptys = new Map<ID, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, (SELECT id, 
         Discount, listprice, name, 
         opportunityid, Product2Id, unitprice, 
         Quantity,totalprice FROM opportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id in :oppids]);
```

**This is the FOR loop**

```
for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
```

And while in the loop, I want to go over all the olis.

Current code is:

```
for ( OpportunityLineItem oli : opptys.get(opp.Id) )
        {
            .....
            jsGen.writeNumberField('ListPrice', oli.ListPrice);
            ....
        }
```

which throws an error that

**Loop must iterate over a collection type: SOBJECT:Opportunity**

Which is understood, as I have a map of opptys.

However, if I change the for to be of opptys:

```
for ( Opportunity oli : opptys.get(opp.Id) )
        {
            .....
            jsGen.writeNumberField('ListPrice', oli.ListPrice);
            ....
        }
```

The error is (and correct) that ListPrice is NOT a field in Opportunity - which is true. But ListPrice field is in the MAP (the select has this field)

Also, the smarttext shows ListPrice - as of OpportunityLineItemField

[image]

So My Loops/For/Maps are misplaced somewhere, how do I iterate over them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since opportunityLineItems is a level 'deeper' then opportunity, you need to do an inner loop through the opportunityLineItems of the Opportunity that your have picked from the map:

```
for ( Opportunity o : opptys.get(opp.Id) )
        {

            for ( OpportunityLineItem oli : o.OpportunityLineItems) )
                {
                    .....
                    jsGen.writeNumberField('ListPrice', oli.ListPrice);
                    ....       
                }
            ....
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to have a map to maintain it. Just go one level down and have the child objects

```
for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : opp.OpportunityLineItems){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

You may need to check the correct relationship name in the `WSDL`.